# ¿Cómo enviar datos en sesión activa mediante Ajax?

Tags: php, ajax

Tengo iniciada las variables en el archivo actual, ya sea mediante `POST` o `GET`, por ejemplo:

```
if (isset($_GET['email']) && preg_match('/^([a-zA-Z0-9])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-])*@([a-zA-Z0-9_-])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+)+$/', $_GET['email'])) {
    $email = $_GET['email'];
}
if (isset($email)) {
    SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE email=?
   //...
}
```

Ahora mediante sesiones de usuario logueados

```
if (isset($_SESSION["id_username"])) { 
  if (!filter_var($_SESSION["id_username"] ?: '', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) === false) {
    $id_username = $_SESSION["id_username"] ?: '';
  }
}
```

Ahora por datos a imprimir del usuario de manera gloabal

```
$Username->bind_result($email,$nombres,$ciudad //.... );
```

Yo dispongo de todos estos datos, en mis aplicaciones utilizo `ajax`, y solo deseo poder agregar campos `input` que sean necesarios y los que no sean necesarios poderlos enviar esa información directamente desde el código `ajax` sin la necesidad de crear campos `input` ocultos, ya que cada `formulario` tiene un `id` de identificación, la cual el `ajax` solo funciona para dicho formulario `var frm = $('#resetform');`.

¿Entonces como puedo enviar esa informaciones sin la necesidad de crear un campo input? por ejemplo `<input type="hidden" name="email" value="<?php echo $email;?>">`

este valor `$email;` se puede enviar directamente con el código ajax, algún parámetro, me invento `var $email` y así enviar esa información.

```
$(function() {
var frm = $('#resetform');
frm.submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = frm.serialize();
    formData += '&' + $('#submit_btn').attr('name') + '=' + $('#submit_btn').attr('value');
 var url = "update.php";
    $.ajax({
        type: frm.attr('method'),
        url: url,
        data: formData,
    })
    .done(function(data) {
        let res = JSON.parse(data);
        if(res.status){
            $('#message').fadeIn();
            $('#message').html(res.message).delay(3000).fadeOut(3000);
            $(frm).hide();
    setTimeout(function(){
        location.href = 'index.php';
    },2000);
  } else {
    $('#message').fadeIn();
    $('#message').html(res.message).delay(3000).fadeOut(3000);
  }
    })
    .fail(function() {
        $('#message').fadeIn();
        $('#message').html(textStatus).delay(2000).fadeOut(2000);
    })
});
});
```

Comment: Como obtienes la sessión del PHP? por un ajax? o el controlador se lo manda a la vista en primera instancia?

Comment: @DavidLeonardoMolinaRuizDav Acabo de editar mi pregunta, espero se haya aclarado todo el asunto al respecto, saludos :)

Comment: Creo entenderte, creo que la mejor manera es usar new FormData(), con jquery puedes usarlo de la siguiente manera: var frm = new FormData($('#resetform')[0]); alli tienes todos los campos y valores de tu formulario y aparte puedes agregar nuevos con el append quedaria algo como: frm.append( 'email', valor ); y asi por cada valor que quieres insertar en ese formData y te evitas el crear campos ocultos, avisame si me supe explicar asi edito mi respuesta con un ejemplo.

Comment: @DavidLeonardoMolinaRuizDav Sí de esa manera estaría muy bien

Comment: Quieres que edite mi respuesta o ya la tienes claro?

Comment: Ya edite mi respuesta, espero te sirva

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Editado**

Creo que te vendría bien usar **new FormData()**, donde puedes almacenar todos los datos de los campos de tu formulario y aparte agregar nuevos valores sin tener que agregar campos ocultos, voy hacer referencia en la parte de tu código en donde lo necesitas. Ejemplo:

```
$(function() {

var frm = $('#resetform');

frm.submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var email = '<?php echo $email;?>';
    var otrovalor = '<?php echo $otrovalor;?>';        

    //Este es el FormData con tu formulario
    var formData = new FormData($('#resetform')[0])
    formData.append('email',email);
    formData.append('otrovalor',otrovalor);       

...
```

Si te fijas la variable **formData** almacenaria todo tu formulario **#resetform** y después de inicializarlo puedes agregar valores aparte como haciendo un push a un array con el **append**, espero esta respuesta si te sirva.

**Otra forma con $_COOKIE**

Como te habia dicho otra manera de hacerlo sin tener qu mezclar el php con el js es crear cookies desde el php y leerlo desde el js:

**PHP**

```
<?php
$email = 'prueba@prueba.com';
$idUsuario = 12;

setcookie("email", $email);
setcookie("idUsuario", $idUsuario);
?>
```

Las sesiones usan una cookie como una especie de clave, para asociar los datos que se almacenan en el lado del servidor. En el servidor cuando creas una sesión o un cookie se crea un archivo en dicho servidor y cuando necesitas leer un valor de esa cookie o sesión la lee de se archivo, las sesiones y las cookies usan el mismo archivo para guardar valores dentro del sevidor para un visitante web. Dicho esto puedes usar cookies tranquilamente para guardar valores como si fuesen sesiones. Ahora la idea despues seria leer los valores en el **js** asi:

```
$(document).ready(() => {

  const email = getCookie("email");
  const idUsuario = getCookie("idUsuario");

  //Aquí puedes crear tu sessionStorages para luego poder
  //leer los valores y mandarlos en cualquier parte de tu js
  //como a la hora de enviar un ajax
  sessionStorage.setItem('email', email);
  sessionStorage.setItem('idUsuario', idUsuario);

});

const getCookie = (cname) => {
   var v = document.cookie.match('(^|;) ?' + cname+ '=([^;]*)(;|$)');
   return v ? v[2] : null;
}
```

Ejemplo cuando necesites rescatar los valores y enviarlos por ajax

```
$.ajax({
   url: url,
   data: {
     email: sessionStorage.getItem('email'),
     idUsuario: sessionStorage.getItem('idUsuario')
   }
...
```

Comment: No acabo de comprender del todo, `formData.append('email',valor);` donde van las variables de PHP? Que le dan el valor al `ajax`

Comment: Yo no soy participe de mezclar php con js pero la respuesta seria: var email =  '<?php echo $email;?>' y luego formData.append('email',email); ya lo edito en la respuesta

Comment: Si no es así, entonces como enviaría los datos de las variables, sin tener que mezclar php con js? O Existe alguna otra alternativa.

Comment: Ojo no es que este mal, es depende de cada quien, yo en el document ready llamo a un función que tiene un ajax y este ajax hace una petición obteniendo los valores de la session y los almaceno en variables como sessionStorages o localStorages y así tengo puro js sin mezclar con php, lo otro seria crear cookie en el php y obtenerlas directo en el js a través de document.cookie, cual es el pro de hacer esto?, que puede tener todo tu js en un archivo .js y a la hora de hacer mantenimiento se te hace mas fácil y no se te es mas engorroso porque tienes todo mezclado. No esta mal lo tuyo

Comment: Entiendo, cuando dispongas de tiempo puedes crear un ejemplo de cado uno, con sus pro y desventajas, pero sin borrar el código que has dado al momento, así lo puedo analizar a futuro, y sobre todo para que la respuesta sea de gran ayuda para futuros lectores de StackOverflow.

Comment: Claro que si, mañana lo haré ya es tarde en mi país, si te sirvió alguna de las respuestas acuérdate de tildarla como aceptada, saludos

Comment: ya agregue otro método como te decia, saludos

Comment: Amigo disculpa que sea tan abusivo, y sobre el uso de esto: ***yo en el document ready llamo a un función que tiene un ajax y este ajax hace una petición obteniendo los valores de la session y los almaceno en variables como sessionStorages o localStorages y así tengo puro js sin mezclar con php***  sin usar la cookie en el php, el ejemplo está muy bien los puedes dejar para futuras referencias, pero tengo curiosidad sobre ello que me indicaste en el comentario más aún cuando no me gusta casí utilizar las `cookie`

Comment: Perfecto lo de ajax, puedes dejarlo asi y no usas las cookies sino que con el ajax en el document ready haces una petición al php para obtener las sesiones y almacenarlas en variables o localstorages

Answer (score 0):

Solo creamos un formulario vacio, sin ningun campo

```
<form action="ruta.php" method="post" id="pay" name="pay" >

</form>
```

Luego capturamos el evento submit, y agregamos el Campo que necesitamos con el valor necesario

```
<script>

 $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#pay").on("submit",function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
       // alert("Capturado");


           var form = document.querySelector('#pay');

            var card = document.createElement('input');
            card.setAttribute('name',"token");
            card.setAttribute('type',"hidden");
            card.setAttribute('value',<?php echo $email; ?>);
            form.appendChild(card);
            doSubmit=true;
          form.submit();

      })



        })
</script>
```

Comment: Tenía la esperanza de que fuera algo más sencillo, a lo que tenía en mente :(

Answer (score 0):

si logré entender bien tu pregunta, pues mi solución sería la siguiente. Tú no quieres tener campos input extras en tu formulario, pues perfecto, mezcla con ajax jquery los datos que desees enviar. Realmente no se que sentido tiene que reenvies al servidor datos que el usuario no modifica pero bueno, es tu solución y sabrás por lo que lo haces. Yo lo haría de varias formas, esta es una:

código:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="txtNombre" id="txtNombre" placeholder="nombre">
    <button id="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#submit').click(function(){
        var nombre = $('#txtNombre').val();
        var email = <?php echo $email;?>
        $.ajax({
            async:true,
            type: "POST",
            url:"update.php",
            data:{
                nombre: nombre,
                email: email,
            },
            beforeSend:function(){},//FUNCION PARA ANTES DE ENVIAR
            success: function(response){},//FUNCION AL OBTENER RESPUESTA
            error: function(){}, //FUNCION PARA SI HAY ERROR
            timeout:4000,//TIEMPO LIMITE DE INTENTO
        });
    });
</script>
```

Te propongo que crees un código de envio general, algo como esto:

FUNCION GENERICA PARA ENVIAR POR AJAX:

```
    function enviar(form, dataExtra, fncAntes, fncEnviado, fncError){
        $(form).submit(function(e){
            var $this = $(this)
            var data = '';
            for (DE in dataExtra)
                data += DE + '=' + dataExtra[DE] + '&';
            data += $this.serialize()
            $.ajax({
                async:true,
                type: "POST",
                url: $this.attr('action'),
                data: data,
                beforeSend: fncAntes,//FUNCION PARA ANTES DE ENVIAR
                success: fncEnviado,//FUNCION AL OBTENER RESPUESTA
                error: fncError, //FUNCION PARA SI HAY ERROR
                timeout:4000,//TIEMPO LIMITE DE INTENTO
            });
            e.preventDefault();
        })
    }
```

Ahora imagina que este sea tu campo del formulario:

```
<form id="form1" action="update.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="txtNombre" id="txtNombre" placeholder="nombre">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="enviar">
</form>
```

Solo tendrías que crear el evento click siguiente para todos los formularios que desees enviar más contenido extra con AJAX:

```
    $('#submit').click(function(){
        enviar("form#form1", {'email': <?php echo $email;?>, 'edad': <?php echo $edad;?>}, function(){}, function(response){}, function(){})
    })
```

Siempre es bueno aplicar patrones de diseño y generalizar tú código. Espero que te sirva. Saludos!

Comment: Hola gracias por el tiempo dedicado, ***Realmente no se que sentido tiene que reenvíes al servidor datos que el usuario no modifica*** en sí, quiero usar esta alternativa cuando el usuario pide restablecer la contraseña y así tener que evitar el uso de `input` ocultos donde puede ser vulnerable a ediciones, y por otros temas de interés.

Comment: Por lo general los grandes framework como Symfony, Django ... usan input en blanco con un código hash contra los ataques CSRF, puedes hacer algo similar, donde ese hash corresponda a la cantidad y tipo de elementos, más el token de autenticación, es decir, un hash único y reconocido por el servidor, para cuando se envie este desde el cliente, toda variación hecha en el formulario, estamos hablando de inclusiones nuevas de código... pues al realizar el hash de nuevo no coincide con el de envio. No sé si me pudistes entender bien. Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

no es necesario capturar los datos para mandarlos por AJAX, por lo que veo ya existen en $_SESSION, por lo tanto dichos datos los tienes en el lado del servidor, no es necesario, de lo que comentas de enviar solo los datos específicos podrías hacer la petición AJAX así:

$.ajax({
        type: frm.attr('method'),
        url: url,
        data: { key:value, key2:value2 },
        // ajax code here...
    });

Answer (score 0):

Bueno ya ha pasado varios años desde esta publicación pero estoy seguro que al igual que yo a alguien mas se le producirá esta duda a futuro.

Si usted esta seguro de que sus variables de sesión que ha creado están bien propagadas por todo su sistema, entonces la solución es solo actualizar la session_start, que por algún motivo cuando se accede a un script de php mediante Ajax las variables de session que usted ya creo están pero no son accesibles o no las encuentra la petición, lo único que tendría que hace es algo como esto:

```
public function pruebaSesionAjax(){

    /**PRIMERO VERICAMOS SI EL ESTATUS DE NUESTRA SESION ESTA ACTIVA , DE ESTARLO REANUDAMOS LA SESION CON session_start()**/
    /**DE ESTA MANERA ACCEDEMOS A TODAS LAS VARIABLES DE SESSION QUE YA ESTEN CREADAS**/
    
    if (session_status()==1) {
        session_start(); 

        echo $_SESSION["prueba"]; //esta variable sesion ya fue definida 
        //devolvemos la resuesta con un echo a ajax para la verificacion
    }

}
```